# I want to remove the special character and convert the next letter to uppercase "the-stealth-warrior" in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String name = "the-stealth-warrior";
      for (int i = 0; i < name.length();i++){
         if (name.charAt(i) == '-'){
             char newName = Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(i+1));
             newName += name.charAt(i + 1);
             i++;
         }
      }
    }
}
```

I try to loop in every char and check if the I == '-' convert the next letter to be uppercase and append to a new String.

Comment: You could at least say what’s wrong and what is the expected output for your string. Is it theStealthWarrior? Is it TheStealthWarrior?

Comment: The problem is that you're not actually changing the string - all you're doing is changing the value of `newName`, which is a local variable. And using `+=` with a `char` is basically never a useful thing to do, because e.g. `'A' + 'A'` isn't `'AA'`, it's whatever codepoint 130 is.

Comment: The input is "the-stealth-warrior", and the output should be "theStealthWarrior"

Comment: What if `-` is at the end of the string, so no character follows it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most concise way to do this would be with regexes:

```
String newName = Pattern.compile("-+(.)?").matcher(name).replaceAll(mr -> mr.group(1).toUpperCase());
```

Note that `Pattern.compile(...)` can be stored rather than re-evaluating it each time.

A more verbose (but probably more efficient way) to do it would be to build the string using a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name.length());
boolean uc = false;  // Flag to know whether to uppercase the char.
int len = name.codePointsCount(0, name.length());
for (int i = 0; i < name.len; ++i) {
  int c = name.codePointAt(i);
  if (c == '-') {
    // Don't append the codepoint, but flag to uppercase the next codepoint
    // that isn't a '-'.
    uc = true;
  } else {
    if (uc) {
      c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
      uc = false;
    }
    sb.appendCodePoint(c);
  }
}
String newName = sb.toString();
```

Note that you can't reliably uppercase single codepoints in specific locales, e.g. `ß` in `Locale.GERMAN`.

Answer (score 2):

We can try using a split approach with the help of a stream:

```java
String name = "the-stealth-warrior";
String parts = name.replaceAll("^.*?-", "");
String output = Arrays.stream(parts.split("-"))
                      .map(x -> x.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + x.substring(1))
                      .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
output = name.split("-", 2)[0] + output;
System.out.println(output);  // theStealthWarrior
```

Comment: Check the updated answer.